# When is the quadratic congruence $ax^2 + bx +c \equiv 0 \pmod p$ solvable?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-reciprocity

I am learning about quadratic congruences and I don't now how to decide, for which $a, b, c$ and $p$ there is a solution of the congruence. Is it sufficient if the discrminant $b^2-4ac$ has a solution in $\Bbb Z_p^*$?

Comment: Yes it is. But the discriminant is the thing under the radical, not including it. Solution will exist if this discrimanent is a square mod $p$. Then to get the answer consult "quadratic residues" or maybe "quadratic reciprocity" if the prime $p$ is large.

Comment: You do have to treat the cases $p=2$ and $a \equiv 0 \mod p$ separately.

Answer (score 9):

If $a = 0$, this reduces to a linear congruence which has a unique solution (provided $b \neq 0$); I assume you know how to find the solution in this case.

Now suppose $a \neq 0$.

If $\underline{p \neq 2}$, multiply the congruence by $4a$ to obtain $4a^2x^2 + 4abx + 4ac \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Completing the square gives $(2ax + b)^2 + 4ac - b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Now let $y = 2ax + b$, then the congruence becomes $y^2 \equiv b^2 - 4ac \pmod p$. Therefore the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ must be a square modulo $p$ (i.e. a square in $\mathbb{Z}_p$); we call such an element a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $p$.

If $b^2 - 4ac$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then the congruence has no solutions.

If $b^2 - 4ac$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then there are two values of $y$, call them $y_1$, $y_2$, which solve $y^2 \equiv b^2 - 4ac$. Furthermore, these two values are negatives of each other, i.e. $y_2 = - y_1$. Note that it is possible that $y_1 = y_2$, namely when $b^2 - 4ac = 0$ in which case $y_1 = y_2 = 0$. For each value $y_i$, we obtain a value $x_i$ by solving the linear congruence $2ax_i + b \equiv y_i \pmod p$ which has a solution because $a \neq 0$. Note that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct if and only if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are distinct.

In summary, the equivalence $ax^2 + bx + c \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has

\begin{align*}
\text{no solutions}\ &\text{if}\ b^2 - 4ac\ \text{is not a quadratic residue}\\
\text{one solution}, x = 0\ &\text{if}\ b^2 - 4ac = 0\\
\text{two distinct solutions}\ &\text{if}\ b^2 - 4ac\ \text{is a non-zero quadratic residue modulo}\ p.
\end{align*}

The problem of determining whether or not $b^2 - 4ac$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ can be solved by using the [law of quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

If $\underline{p = 2}$, then as $a \neq 0$, $a = 1$ so the congruence becomes $x^2 + bx + c \equiv 0 \pmod 2$. If $x = 0$, then we obtain the congruence $c \equiv 0 \pmod 2$; if $x = 1$, then we obtain the congruence $b + c \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. With these conditions at hand, we can determine the solutions for all four possible congruences:

\begin{align*}
x^2 &\equiv 0 \pmod 2\ \text{has one solution,}\ x = 0\\
x^2 + 1 &\equiv 0 \pmod 2\ \text{has one solution,}\ x = 1\\
x^2 + x &\equiv 0 \pmod 2\ \text{has two solutions,}\ x= 0, 1\\
x^2 + x + 1 &\equiv 0 \pmod 2\ \text{has no solutions.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi, sorry if this is way to broad for a comment, but is there any easy way to determine when a degree $n$ polynomial $p$ has solutions $p \equiv 0 \pmod 2$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: If $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, then $x = 0$ is a solution to $p(x) \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ if and only if it has constant term zero, and $x = 1$ is a solution if and only if the number of non-zero coefficients is even.