# Find the solution for $x$ with $0 \le x \lt 13$ so $13 \mid 3x^2+9x+7 $.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Find the solution for $x$ with $0 \le x \lt 13$ so $13 \mid 3x^2+9x+7 $.
I got this question in my discrete mathematics class.
I don't really get the idea how 13 can divide $3x^2+9x+7 $ 
All of my friend told me to try all the number between 0 and 12, but I know that's not how to solve this question.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Just note that there are also systematic approaches that work for high numbers as well (withou trial and error), see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210199/solvability-of-quadratic-congruence, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341817/find-all-values-of-p-such-that-ax2bxc-equiv-0-bmod-p-have-solution, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551700/when-is-the-quadratic-congruence-ax2-bx-c-equiv-0-pmod-p-solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work in $\mod 13$. We want $3x^2+9x+7 \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$.  Now $7 \equiv -6$ so you have $3x^2+9x-6 \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$. Because $\gcd(3, 13) = 1$, we can "divide both sides" by $3$ and get $x^2+3x-2 \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$

Notice that $-2 \equiv -28$, so $x^2+3x-28 \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$ which you can factor to $(x-4)(x+7)\equiv 0 \pmod {13}$. Because $13$ is prime, we have $x \equiv 4$ or $x \equiv -7 \equiv 6$.

Comment: Ok, I just don't get it, where did -28 come from? I know that $-2 \equiv -28$ but, how do I know that I should use -28?

Comment: I am asking how do you can think about -28?

Comment: @DifaSanditya A lot of trial and error. Because 13 is prime, I knew from the beginning that if I factor I can solve it, but I saw I can't factor $3x^2 + 9x + 7$. So I tried to factor $3x^2 + 9x + 7+13$, $3x^2 + 9x + 7 + 13 + 13$, etc. (using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+3x%5E2+%2B+9x+%2B+7+-13-13+-13-13-13).  Then I tried $3x^2 + 9x + 7 -13$, and at this step I got $-6$ and saw I can cancel, and so I did, and arrived at $x^2+3x-2 \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$. Then I tried to factor  $x^2+3x-2$, $x^2+3x-2 -13$, $x^2+3x-2 -13-13$, and this last one worked.

Comment: so basically I have to try it until I found the correct one? Thanks then

Comment: @DifaSanditya You're welcome. Maybe there is a better way, but I wasn't scared to try a few times because I knew this problem had answer between $0$ and $13$, so you o not have to subtract or add $13$ too many times. Also because this problem was constructed by somebody as a "riddle", it probably had some trick solution like this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's a perfectly good way to solve this question! You have 13 numbers to check, which sounds quite reasonable.

You can make it a bit easier, though: $7 = 13 - 6$, and $13$ divides the $13$ we just made, so $13 \mid 3x^2+9x+7$ iff $13 \mid 3x^2+9x-6$; that is, iff $13 \mid 3(x^2+3x-2)$; that is, iff $13 \mid x^2+3x-2$. That just makes the numbers a bit simpler.

If you want to be even more clever, notice that $$x^2+3x-2 = x^2+3x-28+26 = (x-4)(x+7) + 2 \times 13$$ so $13 \mid x^2+3x-2$ iff $13 \mid (x-4)(x+7)$. I don't really know how one would come up with that, though, other than magic.

Comment: wait, I still don't get it

Comment: The overall idea of the first two paragraphs is that if $x$ is an integer, then $13$ divides $3x^2+9x+7$ if and only if $13$ divides $x^2+3x-2$.

Comment: I explained in a comment to my answer how I got the $-28$, it was just trial and error.

Comment: Another one is $x^2+3x -54 + (13\cdot4) = (x+9)(x-6) + (13\cdot4)$  but $-9 \equiv 4\pmod{13}$ and $-7 \equiv 6 \pmod {13}$

Comment: Well, I understand now. Thank to everyone for helping me. So in the end I still need a lot of practice to got the idea of $-28$.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant of the equation $3x^2+9x+7=0$ equals $81-4 \cdot 9 \cdot 7=-3=10=7^2 \mod 13$. Taking into account that $3^{-1}=9 \mod 13$  we  have 
$$
x_1=\frac{-9+7}{6}=\frac{-2}{6}=-\frac{-1}{3}=-9=4  \mod 13, 
$$
$$
x_2=\frac{-9-7}{6}=\frac{-16}{6}=\frac{-8}{3}=-8 \cdot 9=5 \cdot 9=45=6  \mod 13. 
$$

Thus $x=4$ and $x=6.$